# Problems with map container

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-asio

**Introduction**

I'm trying to create a port-forwarding sample with tcp connections, so I need map client identification with his socket. When the client requests port-forwarding, I have to know who owns the sockets.

To do that, I created the following code:

```
std::map<std::string, tcp::socket> box_map;

std::map<std::string, tcp::socket>::iterator it;
it = box_map.find(id);
if (it != box_map.end())
    return;
else{
    box_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, tcp::socket>(id,s));
    return;
}
```

**Problem**

But I got the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&)’
```

Comment: socket is not copyable as the error states, store `std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` instead: `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcp::socket` is not copy constructible. So you'd have to construct the new pair in-place by moving your socket using [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
box_map.emplace(id, std::move(s));
```

Alternatively, you could just still use `insert` and just move into the `pair` you're constructing:

```
box_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(s)));
```

Comment: that tcp::socket was a bug in question not in code. I will edit.  thanks.
I tried do std::make_pair and dont work.  I updated the question.

Comment: @AndréLizardo You need to `move` the socket, updated my answer.